# How can I use "const" in epic? Redux-observable ES6 arrow function

Tags: javascript, redux-observable

I'm new to react and redux-observable.

My question is How to define variable in epic?

I was told to use
    const { user } = store.getState().currentUser.user
I tried, but it didn,t work.

() => request() is API like fetch.

before

```
const updateDeviceTokenEpic = (action$: Observable<Action>, store: any) => action$.pipe(
  ofType(actions.UPDATE_DEVICE_TOKEN),
  exhaustMap(() => request({
    url: `users/${store.getState().currentUser.user.id}`,
    method: 'put',
    data: {
      device_token: `${store.getState().currentUser.user.deviceToken}`,
    },
  })),
  ignoreElements(),
);
```

after

```
const updateDeviceTokenEpic = (action$: Observable<Action>, store: any) => 
action$.pipe(
  ofType(actions.UPDATE_DEVICE_TOKEN),
  exhaustMap(() => request(
    const { user } = store.getState().currentUSer.user;
    {
    url: user.id,
    method: 'put',
    data: {
      device_token: user.deviceToken,
    },
  })),
  ignoreElements(),
);
```

What is wrong?
Is there js ninja?

Comment: in fact, this works  `const { user } = store.getState().currentUser`, without `.user`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove braces around user and it will work you are using [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and have no idea how it works and add braces to function body.

```
const updateDeviceTokenEpic = (action$: Observable<Action>, store:any) =>
{
    const user = store.getState().currentUSer.user;
    return action$.pipe(
        ofType(actions.UPDATE_DEVICE_TOKEN),
        exhaustMap(() => request({
            url: `users/${user.id}`,
            method: 'put',
            data: {
                device_token: user.deviceToken,
            },
        })),
        ignoreElements(),
    );
}
```

Without braces in [Arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) you can write only one code statement which is also default return value too. If you want to write more than 1 statement use braces and return a value explicitly.

Comment: I resolved this error.
exhaustMap(() => {
  const user = store.getState().currentUser.user;
  request({
 ...
}
works.

Thanks a lot Rehan!!!

Comment: Above code is correct I think you also had to return result of `action$.pipe`. Simply put `return` before `action$.pipe` like this `return action$.pipe`.

Comment: That is nice idea,
and my code is wrong.
const user = store.getState().currentUser.user;
return request({
...
works.

Comment: Your code is also correct but there are more than one ways to do a thing.

Comment: Would you like to accept my answer?
Please also visit links given in description to understand how arrow function works.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
const updateDeviceTokenEpic = (action$: Observable<Action>, store: any) => 
const { id } = store.getState().currentUSer.user;
action$.pipe(
 ofType(actions.UPDATE_DEVICE_TOKEN),
exhaustMap(() => request(

{
url: `users/${id}`,
method: 'put',
data: {
  device_token: user.deviceToken,
},
})),
ignoreElements(),
);
```